# Two mavens projects deployed: How to have the same URI?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss

I'm working on a project that has 2 mavens projects: the rest server and the webapp.
Is it possible that both have the same URI?

Example: rest server uri would be http://localhost:8080/proj/rest
webapp uri would be http://localhost:8080/proj/

Is this possible? Because I can only have these two deployed if I change the root context of one of the projects.
I also created a jboss_web.xml - Do i need this file on both projects?

I hope I could explain my problem ok.

thanks everyone.

Comment: Does this solve your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366630/maven-war-plugin-copy-src-main-webapp-to-classes

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot have two webapps expecting to handle the same URI.

Typically, the URI for a REST server will start with "/api" or "/msapi". You can't nest the REST URI within the webapp URI.